# keep current browser session across functions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am logging into a website and attempting to change the URL in a different function while remaining logged in. When I do change the page it reverts back to the login page (as if never logged in).I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I am redirecting with a direct URL so I don't have to navigate the forms to change pages.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import cookielib
from mechanize import Browser
import urllib2

#login information
username = 'user'
password = 'password'

#creates browser
def browser():
        br = Browser()
        cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
        br.set_cookiejar(cj)
        br.set_handle_robots(False)
        return br


#connect and login to site
class connSite:
    def login(self):
        url = "https://www.website.com"
        br = browser()
        br.open(url)

        #find login form
        br.form = list(br.forms())[0]
        control = br.form.find_control("login")
        control.readonly = False

        #pass login
        br['username'] = username
        #submit login
        response = br.submit()

        #find password form
        br.form = list(br.forms())[0]
        control = br.form.find_control("password")
        control.readonly = False

        #pass password
        br['password'] = password

        #submit login
        response = br.submit()
        return response

#gets first logged in page
def loginPage():
    conn = connSite()
    conn.login()
    bs = BeautifulSoup(conn.login())
    return bs

#get balance
def balance():
    page = loginPage()
    # find balance
    elements = page.find(class_="col notFirst")
    balance = elements.find("h1")
    for bal in balance:
        balance = bal
    balance.replace("<h1>", "")
    balance.replace("</h1>", "")
    return balance

#pay
def payPage():
    url = "https://www.website.com/servicing/Payment.action"
    br = browser()

    loginPage()
    br.open(url)

    form = list(br.forms())[0]

    for f in br.forms():
        print f.name

payPage()
```

Comment: You need to pass the browser object into the functions and return it when you're done. Or you could create a class to do this. Your code needs some work in general.

Comment: yeah, I'm new to python. I'm actually just doing this to learn. Its not good code, Im working on it.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Sorry if that sounded harsh; I didn't mean it to. Everyone has to start somewhere :).

Comment: No, its bad. I just have a couple of weeks under my belt. Help me understand what you are saying though. I return the page at "return bs" under loginpage. I call loginpage from paypage then redirect from there...Why is that incorrect?

Comment: It's the `Browser()` object that you need to keep active. It's hard to recommend fixes to the code, as opposed to just rewriting the whole thing.

Comment: ok, ill start from scratch. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more. Maybe I'll take a look at rewriting it later :).

Comment: @NeonLights86:  It's not completely unfixable.  You should turn all your functions into instance methods on a single class, and store your `Browser()` in an instance variable, so it's available everywhere.

Comment: I was learning about classes and decided to make the connect a class of its own, I'm not sure that was necessary but I wanted to try it and figured it would be safer. I'll see If i can fix it. Thanks.

Comment: The `connSite` class as it is now is entirely unnecessary; you could just have the `login()` function on its own.